# How to download file with Mysql blob without html

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, blob

I am having a problem with downloading blob file, my sql query returns perfect result but while im downloading i am getting download page's html code in it not the blob data. It is important to say that im using wordpress and writing a custom funtion for that. now if i remove the get_header() from page file the output returns perfectly but if the get_header present it returns the htmls. now how can i get rid of it?

here are my download function:

```
   foreach($search_order as $order)
    {   

    header();
    $file_name = 'Li_'. $random_number . '.mg';
    $mimetype = 'application/octet-stream';
    $filedata = $order->data;
    header("Content-length: ".strlen($filedata));
    header("Content-type:" .$mimetype);
    header("Content-disposition: download; filename=" .$file_name);     

    }

    echo $filedata;
```

and in page.php i put this to call the function:

```
downloadFile($order_id);

echo "<td><a href=?id=" . $search->order .">download file</a>";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK

I found the answer, you have to call the function before the get_header(); but my analysis states that, if you want to download pdf or any other file you have call that before the  tag to get rid of the html injection.

hope this helps to others